# Time changes into datetime Excel(Numbers)

Tags: excel, date, time, numbers

I have currently the following problem:

When i just simple want to enter a specific time in a cell, for example: 09:30
It automaticly converts the cell into :4 maart 2012 09:30:00
But it only shows 09:30 in the cell..

How can i stop this convertion, so that only 09:30 stays in the cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is more to this problem than the answers below suggest. Excel holds dates and times as numbers. 4 March 2012 is held as integer 40972 (days since 1 January 1900). 9:30 is held as a fraction of a day = 9.5/24 = .395933. If I enter 9:30 on my computer, it is stored as .395933. If I format this value as a date and time it displays as: 0 Jan 1900 9:30. But it appears that on Sinan's computer, 9:30 is stored as 40972.395933. We need to explain that effect to solve this problem.

Comment: even mine says `1/0/1900  9:30:00 AM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the cell contents to be interpreted as a date (eg by a formula)? If not, why not enter **'09:30** (with a leading  apostrophe) - excel will just store the string "09:30" in the cell, without converting it to a date.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed. A simple bypass!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefix a value in Excel with the ' character (single quote) Excel will treat it as a string value and not convert to numeric or other data type.

If you want to keep it as a time value and perform calculations on it as such, let Excel convert it, but format the cell to only show the time value, and ignore the date portion.

Date time values in Excel are actually stored as floating point numbers, with the whole number portion representing the number of days since the Epoch date (on my version, 1900/01/00) and the fraction part represents the time.